# Save Not Recognize Faces In a Array

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, face-recognition

I am working on a "Face Recognition" project.
I have done the recognition part, my project is based on 3 code file

1. Face Detection (Taking samples Of Person approx 50)
2. Face Train (Will train the captured images)
3. Face Recognition (Will be able to recognize trained Images at real
   time)

Now what I have to do is if an unknown person which is not in dataset detected more than 3 times in camera, the face recognition program will wait for a wile and the face detection will run which will take samples of the person and train so the next time that person is on the camera he/she will be recognizable. Here is the code For my Face Recognition

```
import cv2
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import picamera 
import numpy as np 
import pickle
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call
import time
import datetime
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import serial

# port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
currentDate = str(now.month) + "_" + str(now.day) + "_" + str(now.year)+ "_" + str(now.hour)
cloudpath ='Videos/cctvfootage'+currentDate+'.mp4'
with open('labels', 'rb') as f:
    dict= pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    #setup the camera
camera =PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (600,500)
camera.framerate = 30
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(600, 500))



# Load prebuilt model for Frontal Face detection
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
# Create Local Binary Patterns Histograms for face recognization
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
# Load the trained mode
recognizer.load("trainer.yml")

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(cloudpath, fourcc, 2.0, (camera.resolution))
lastRes=''
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    frame = frame.array
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (455, 30), (0,0,0), thickness=-1)
    cv2.putText(frame, time.asctime(), (10, 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 255, 0), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, thickness=2)  
    data = open(cloudpath, 'rb') 
     # Convert the captured frame into grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor = 1.5, minNeighbors = 5)
    # For each face in faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
         # Create rectangle around the face
        roiGray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
# Recognize the face belongs to which ID
        id_, conf = recognizer.predict(roiGray)
        
        for name, value in dict.items():
            if value == id_:
             break
             print(name)
             print(conf)
#agar confidence <=70 hoga toh door open hoga wrna nhi
                     # Put text describe who is in the picture
        if conf <= 70:
            
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x-20,y-20), (x+w+20,y+h+20), (0,255,0), 4)
            cv2.putText(frame,name,(x,y-40), font, 1, (255,255,255), 3)
           
            
        else:
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x-20,y-20), (x+w+20,y+h+20), (0,255,0), 4)
            cv2.putText(frame,"Unknown", (x,y-40), font, 1, (255,255,255),3)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    out.write(frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    rawCapture.truncate(0)  
#if cross button is pressed close the cam
    if key == 27:
        print("Video Saved Successfully..")
        break               
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: anyone help plz

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deepface? Its stream function accesses your web cam and applies real time face recognition, and facial attribute analysis (age, gender and emotion prediction) as well. You can switch web cam streaming content to video as well.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream("my_db")
```

Here, my_db is a folder stores my facial database.